Rspec expect to receive not acknoledging a call
I am trying to check a service is called in a test. Here is the error message :
(#<Payments::CardPaymentProvider:0x00007f3ee3a172e0>).debit(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments

Tested class
class Renew

  def initialize
    #....
  end

  def call
    Payments.paymentProviderFactory.provider.debit(amount)
    #...
  end
end

Test
  expect(Payments.paymentProviderFactory.provider).to receive(:debit).once
  subject.call

If I put a debbuger point in debit I can see the method is called but it still fails. What am I doing wrong ?

Please provide the implementation of paymentProviderFactory.provider if this instantiates a new object then you are going to need to stub that to ensure the each call returns the same object.

You are right, it return a new object, expecting a specific implementation of payment provider was the solution.

Solution can be
before { allow(Payments.paymentProviderFactory.provider).to receive(:debit) }

it 'calls debit for provider' do
  subject.call

  expect(Payments.paymentProviderFactory.provider).to have_received(:debit).once
end

